# Create Publish Profile to Azure App Service, throw "The file Exists"

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, publish-profiles

I'm trying to create publish profile to Azure App Service using Visual Studio 2022.
When I created App Service from vs publish dialog (clicking on plus sign button). It threw an error The file exists.

The same error happened when I had created App Service from portal.azure.com.
[image: The file exists]

I've also tried to create publish profile from App Service overview page and import it when creating publish profile in visual studio. But the screen just stops at browse settings file page.

[image: Import publish profile]

I'm not sure if this is useful, but my project are:

- ASP net Core MVC
- .net6

let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

After some time with Microsoft technical support we have solved the problem.

In our case we need to publish the project using FTPS.
This was our settings to get successfully publish this project.

- Server: ftps://[some site name].ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net:990
- FTP site path: /site/wwwroot
- FTP passive mode: True
- Get user name and password from App Service Deployment center (FTPS credentials)
- Destination URL: https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net (from URL in overview page App Service)

That port number (990) was needed for successfully deploy. If you didn't include that port, you will get error

> Could not find a web server at [server url you input]